# Return function value as a value in a dictionary

Tags: function, class, dictionary, object, instance

```
dic1 = {}

class Piglet:
    pass
    def __init__(self,name,age):
            self.name = name
            self.age = age
    def speak_or_not(self):
            if self.age>2:
                    return True
            else:
                    return False
   def speak_dic(self):
            global dic1
            dic1[self.name] = speak_or_not()

pig1  = Piglet("Shaun",3)
pig1.speak_dic()
print(dic1)
```

I want to  add the return value of the function speak_or_not as a value of dictionary dic1 which will result in a output like:  {"Shaun":True} since age>2. But it prints an empty dictionary.
How to call a function and set the return value of the function as a value of the dictionary?

Comment: There are several mistakes in your code (fix indentation). You probably want to `print(dic1)`, and call `self.speak_or_not()` with the `self` prefix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is not correct. In the speak_dic function, you are calling speak_or_not, which does not exist. Instead, you need to call self.speak_or_not.

Attaching the corrected code below.

```
dic1 = {}
class Piglet:
    def __init__(self,name,age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
    def speak_or_not(self):
        if self.age>2:
            return True
        else:
            return False
    def speak_dic(self):
        global dic1
        dic1[self.name] = self.speak_or_not()

pig1  = Piglet("Shaun",3)
pig1.speak_dic()
print(pig1)
```

Also, you need to print dic1 to show the dictionary.

Hope this helps.